# Custom ATMEGA2560 with RS-232 Communication Problem

Tags: serial, atmega, rs232

I made a custom PCB using ATMEGA2560 with 2 [MAX3223](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3221-MAX3243.pdf) RS-232 ICs (because they were available to me) but only one Tx channel is working on both ICs and I can't receive anything on any of them. I tried all the baud rates but no change, since I was suspecting the MCU was not working at 16 MHz. But everything else works fine.

[image: Schematic]

U3 on the left is working without auto-shutdown mode and U4 on the right is working in auto-shutdown mode. I was suspecting the auto-shutdown feature, but no difference as both are having issues. Maybe I missed something, but it's been a week now and I can't figure out what.

Just a note that I bought these ICs from Aliexpress. I do have MAX3225 from Mouser with same footprint. Can I replace MAX3223 with MAX3225 if the IC is bad?

Update: So i did the loopback test with 2 usb to uart cables and it looks like one channel in each IC(max3223) is working perfectly (transmit & receive both).
Second channel is outputting nothing but i plan on connecting the oscilloscope and see what's the result there.

Comment: How are you testing your design? What are the uarts connected to? Have you measured the signals with an oscilloscope?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Peter.
I ran arduino multiserial example and used a usb to serial cable. I monitored the data on a serial terminal. I plan on using oscilloscope to check what's happening on non-working serial channels.

Comment: Is the USB to serial cable RS232 or logic level?

Comment: code please, it may be that you have not enabled the Rx

Comment: Verify you did not mix up the pinout, and inspect soldering.  Probe both the RS232 receive input and the logic level receive output.

Comment: No i made sure of not mixing tx/rx up. Since one channel is working fine so i am sure it's not a mixup.